# Jenkins sending attachments with email plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to attach a file when a test fails in Jenkins.

I'm using the email extension plugin as a means of trying to achieve this but I'm stumped by the syntax.

If I simply put "index.php" (without quotation marks) in the attachment field it will send out the attachment correctly.

If I try and go further into the workspace e.g."myfolder/myfile.php" (without quotation marks) the email wont send. I've tried a number of variants, using wildcards and trying to target files specifically but with no luck.

I have of course looked here http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/fileset.html but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `**/myfile.php`

This will look for `myfile.php` regardless of the directory structure

Comment: is there any way we can attach files that are stored in a directory other than workspace? **Ex: My workspace is C:\JenkinRoot\Project1 but the file I want to attach to the mail is in C:\trial.jpg.**

Comment: Not through Jenkins, as that is a security violation. But you can always have a bash/batch script (if you have enough permissions) that can grab files from wherever and place them into workspace

Comment: Yes. I did the same thing :) I wrote a batch script to zip the files from **C:\trial** and moved it to my workspace. Anyways, Thanks for the reply

Comment: @Rameshwar,I want to attach latest modified file in email ,can you plese help me how to configure in Jenkins.